# Search in private Exchange 2013 mailbox with Sharepoint 2013 Search Center

Tags: 2013, search-results, enterprise-search, exchange-server, ediscovery

Is it possible in any way or what is the best practice to search Exchange 2013 private items (contacts, tasks, mails) from **Sharepoint 2013 Search Center** and show the results in the Sharepoint **Search Results Web Part**.

When searching, only **my own** items should be returned not e.g. mails from another mailbox.

What I have found so far:

- Create an **Exchange Content Source** in Sharepoint 2013 and Crawl that content source=> only possible for Exchange **Public Folders** not **Private Mailboxes**
- Use Outlook Web App => That's possible but it's outside Sharepoint
- Create an Exchange **Result Source** in Sharepoint => That Result Source can be used only in the **eDiscovery Center Sitecollection**. I cannot use that Result Source in the **Search Result Webpart** (Exceptions...). Anybody got this working/integrated in the search center?

Custom Development **is** an option, I just don't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple things you could try. Nothing in SharePoint will let you do this. The only mailbox search that is possible from SharePoint is through eDiscovery and that requires too much overhead.

I would start by trying to do a federated search to Exchange 2013 Search as if the user were performing the same search from Outlook Web Apps. I would investigate the Exchange Web Services and look at any Search APIs that support the features you seek.

Comment: Federated Search to Exchange (use Exchange type result source) doesn't work. I've tried to add a result block for local sharepoint sites => no results. I also tried using that result source directly in "Search Results  Web Part" => Exceptions, saying "Malformed Discovery Query". It seems that you can use an Exchange Result Source only in eDiscovery Center, which is documented here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683115(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: No, I would not expect the SharePoint Exchange connection to work, that is not what it is for. You have to create your own request from Exchange through custom code in SharePoint. So try the Exchange Web Service.