# Search User Mailbox from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, enterprise-search

I have a SharePoint online environment, I am wondering if it is possible to search User Mailbox (exchange Emails) from  SharePoint Search!

I mean, can we achieve it from SharePoint !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search in private Exchange 2013 mailbox with Sharepoint 2013 Search Center](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114060/search-in-private-exchange-2013-mailbox-with-sharepoint-2013-search-center)

Comment: can't it be possible in O365 environment (Exchange online and SharePoint Online) !!